# Eclipse - new blank tab?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to open new blank tab, not associated with any file? It would be better than "create disposable file, use, delete disposable file".

Comment: What do you want it for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to File -> New -> Untitled text file. This opens a text editor with an empty file and when you save it it asks you for the location, if you close it it will dissapear.

This works for text files, not all eclipse editors support creating an "Untitled" file though. Go to File -> New -> Other... to find out which ones do (it usally says "Untitled X file").